# Prove the Cancellation for Congruences making use of the multiplicative inverse

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Prove the cancellation law for congruences: If $ax ≡ ay$ (mod m) and
$gcd(a, m) = 1$, then $x ≡ y$ (mod m). Give two proofs, the first making use of
Euclid’s Lemma, and the second making use of the multiplicative inverse of a.

I've figured out the proof using Euclid's Lemma, but I'm stuck on formulating a proof that involves $a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know $a^{-1}$ exists modulo $m$ (it does since $a$,$m$ are relatively prime) then

$$\begin{align*}ax &= ay \text{ mod m}\\
a^{-1}(ax) &= a^{-1}(ay) \text{ mod m}\\
(a^{-1}a)x &= (a^{-1}a)y \text{ mod m}\\
x &= y \text{ mod m}\end{align*}
$$